# Prove that $a(a^{2}-1)$ is divisible by 6

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, divisibility

*$a$ is a natural number that isn't equal to 0*

My attempt:

$a(a^{2}-1)$ = $a(a-1)(a+1)$

There are 2 cases here:

**If a = 2k:**

We have $2k(2k+1)(2k+1)$ because $a-1$ and $a+1$ come before and after $a$ so if $a$ is even then they are both odd.

By calculation and simplification, we find this:

$8k^{3} + 8k^{2} + 2k$ which is useless because it still doesn't prove that it's divisible by 6

**If a = 2k +1:**

We have $(2k+1)(2k)(2k)$

By calculation and simplification, we find this: $8k^{3} + 4^{2}$ which is also nothing.

Basically what I wanted, in the end, is something of the form $6k$ or at least $3k$ and $2k$ both so that I can say it's divisible by 6, however, I can only prove that they are divisible by 2 which is not enough.

Any help with this?

Comment: You have three consecutive integers. That means one must be divisible by three and at least one of them is even.

Comment: Hint: since $\gcd(2, 3) = 1$, divisibility by $2 \cdot 3$ is equivalent to divisibility by $2$ and $3$.